# Url rewriting for codeigniter

Tags: php

How to rewrite particular url of website using .htaccess or CI routing

http://www.domain.com/user_controller/newfunction/username

as

http://www.domain.com/username

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['/(:any)'] = "/user_controller/newfunction/$1";
```

or try htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user_controller/newfunction/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly error displaying for other urls of websites.

Comment: you should keep something in between like
http://www.domain.com/user_controller/newfunction/username

as

http://www.domain.com/profile/username

Comment: but here I want to show like domain.com/username for this perticular controller.

Answer (score 0):

/application/config/routes.php

```
$route['/all/other/routes/must/come/first!'] = "wherever/you/want";
$route['/(:any)'] = "/user_controller/newfunction/$1";
```

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly error displaying for other urls of websites. Please explain first one with example.

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly

      

      
      
      

      
        
        

Found below error when trying to access other controller of websites.        

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Is there any other way to doing htis, I want to make chnages for this url only not for all url of website?

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use CI routing system found at application/config/routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'user_controller/newfunction/$1';
```

Don't forget to set your base url at application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.domain.com/';
```

Add remember to remove the index.php in the url. Edit your .htaccess file at the root of your site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|_searches|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

now in your user_controller, the function newfunction will look like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class user_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // load things like models, libraries, helpers
    }

    function newFunction($slug)
    {
        echo 'hello my name is'.$slug;
    }
}
```

when you visit http://www.domain.com/nash, your code should print out nash